# Repeating Values based on a cell value in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, arraylist

**Requirement :** Create a range based on input from 3 ranges

[image]

Input 1 : **Words**  - B9:D12

 Input 2 : **Class**  - B4:D5

 Input 3 : **Repeat** -B16:D16

**Output range :** B20:D

**Description :**

1. Repeat each value in the range ***Words***, 'n' times by matching
   the header(Positive, Comparative, Superlative) with the header in
   ***Repeat*** range and list all the values under a single column *Words* in the Output range.

2. For each value in the *Words* column of the output range respective
   type & class needs to be filled.

3. Under *Class* column in the output range, 'A' should be filled for
   the values in 1st & 2nd row of the ***Words*** range. 'B' should be
   filled for the values in 3rd & 4th row of the ***Words*** range.
   (Denoted by color code) in the image

4. Under *Type* column in the output range, list the respective
   header(from ***Words*** range) of each value in column *Words* (in
   the Output range).

**Formulae Required:**

- To list the words in a single column.
- To list the respective class.
- To list the respective type.

I am new to using complicated formulae. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Edit: untagged 'Excel`. Excel works different then Google Sheets.

Comment: This is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1imZAXhbUc2rTRQgrWjuko9_rxNltJHbw5D9snrPXnI0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Just a note: it seems you will be using this in an educational setting with students, and yet you've spelled the word "Comparative" incorrectly all throughout your sheet (at least what we can see, where you've misspelled it as "Comapritive"). I suggest you correct those misspellings.